# Wordpress oEmbed not working when echoing Vimeo link

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, custom-post-type, oembed

I'm creating a film portfolio and I have created the custom post type for portfolio items with a field for the Vimeo link. WordPress is not automatically embedding Vimeo links when I echo the url onto the page and is instead the url is displaying as plain text. I've tested by creating a post with the video link and that is auto-embedding just fine. Heres the code I'm using:

```
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'vimeo_link', TRUE); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, WordPress doesn't oEmbed inside of actual theme files. Instead, you'll need to do something like this

```
 if (get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'vimeo_link', true) != '') {
      <iframe src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'vimeo_link', TRUE); ?>?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
 }
```

[if statement reference](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-an-if-exists-for-custom-field-keys#post-795116)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just need to make some minor changes and everything is working great. Here is the code I ended up using:

`<?php if (get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'vimeo_link', true) != ' ') { ?>

  <div class="videoLightBox" id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'vimeo_link', TRUE); ?>?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="209" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>    
  </div>

 <?php } ?>`